# Import json data with null values

Tags: json, null, google-bigquery, data-import

From the [import](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/import#jsonformat) documentation of BigQuery,

> Note: Null values are not allowed

So I assume `null` is not allowed in a json-formatted data for BigQuery import. However, `null` value is actually very common in regular ETL task (due to missing data). What should be a good solution to import such json source files? Note my data contains nested structures so I do not prefer a conversion to `CSV` and use `,,` to represent a `null` value.

One way I think I can do is to replace all `null` values with default values of different data types respectively, e.g.,

- string: `null` -> empty string
- integer: `null` -> -1
- float: `null` -> -1.0
- ...

But I don't like it. I am looking for better options.

BTW, I tried to do `bq load` with a json file containing `null` values. I get the below error:

```
Failure details:
- Expected '"' found 'n'
- Expected '"' found 'n'
- Expected '"' found 'n'
- Expected '"' found 'n'
- Expected '"' found 'n
...
```

I think this is the indication of `null` usage, is it correct?

**EDIT**: If I remove all the `null` fields, it seems to work. I guess this is the way to handle the `null` data. You cannot have `null` for a data field, but you can just not include it. So I need to have a filtering code to remove all the `null` field in my raw json.

Comment: NULL is allowed in JSON syntax.  Different JSON packages use different software constructs to represent NULL -- either an explicit NULL object, or something like an empty array.  But the messages you quote tell us very little.

Comment: But note that JSON is only a data format -- it does not describe semantics, and the semantics of the data must be agreed to by both ends of the "conversation".  If NULL is not in the agreed-to semantics then JSON has nothing to do with it.  The "BigQuery" document defines some rather restricted semantics.

Comment: Yeah, this might be the restriction of BigQuery import. I just want to know if there is any smart way to avoid the limitation.

Comment: You can maybe use something (eg, an empty array) as a "stand-in".  I don't really know what BigQuery is doing or what you're doing with it, though -- you have to look at your use of it to see what tricks you can play.

Comment: (Note that, in JSON, there's no requirement that a particular data item be of a specific type.  Eg, "phone_number" can be character one time, integer the next time, and an array (or even "object") the third time.  So to represent a "null" integer, you do not have to use an integer value.

Comment: BigQuery enforces that. Once phone_number is a string in its table schema, you cannot change it any more unless you create a new table.

Comment: Well, you can always make everything a string and interpret them yourself.  Or accompany nullable fields with a "null" attribute that's true or false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can import NULL values using JSON format source files - omit the key:value pair for values that are NULL.

Example - Let's say you have a schema like this:

```
{
"name": "kind",
"type": "string"
},
{
"name": "fullName",
"type": "string",
},
{
"name": "age",
"type": "integer",
"mode": "nullable"
}
```

A record with no NULL values might look like this:

```
{"kind": "person",
 "fullName": "Some Person",
 "age": 22
}
```

However, when "age" is NULL, try this (note, no "age" key):

```
{"kind": "person",
 "fullName": "Some Person",
}
```

Please let us know if you have issues with this. I'll make a note to improve the documentation around using NULL values with JSON import formats.

Comment: Thanks. This confirmed that I need to omit null (key,value) pairs.

Comment: This doesn't help if pre-processing your upload involves many gigabytes of data. For example, when loading log files of click data from a web server