# How to check if null values present in JSON object column in BigQuery Table

Tags: google-bigquery, null

I referred GCP Big query documentation as shown below link but there is no luck achieving the objective about using these functions to retrieve the non-null valued JSON data type column values from a Big Query Table.

Ref help: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json-data#json_nulls

Example Select Query: Select column1 from EMP where column1 != 'null'

Comment: Can you provide sample data and your expected sample output for proper replication?

Answer (score 4):

When you try to compare JSON type with other type, you'll get

```sql
SELECT JSON "null" != 'null'
```

> No matching signature for operator != for argument types: JSON, STRING. Supported signature: ANY != ANY at [1:8]

Simple workaround for this is to convert JSON data to BigQuery String and compare it with others.

```sql
WITH json_data AS (
  SELECT CAST(null AS JSON) AS col1 UNION ALL
  SELECT JSON 'null' UNION ALL
  SELECT JSON '{"a":null}' UNION ALL
  SELECT JSON '{"b":"hello"}'
)
SELECT *, FORMAT('%t', col1) format, JSON_TYPE(col1) json_type,
  FROM json_data;
```

[image]

`FORMAT()` and [`JSON_TYPE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_type) function convert `JSON 'null'` to BigQuery string respectively. Utilizing one of these output, you can *retrieve the non-null valued JSON data type column values*

```sql
SELECT * FROM json_data WHERE JSON_TYPE(col1) != 'null';
```

or,

```sql
SELECT * FROM json_data WHERE LOWER(FORMAT('%t', col1)) != 'null';
```

Note **FORMAT()** turns *`null`* into `NULL` string.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON_TYPE assuming you want to find all values that are not explicit JSON NULLs?

```
Select column1 from EMP where JSON_TYPE(column1) != 'null'
```