# Simplifying json sort in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-bigquery

---

I have the following (valid) query to sort some json values based on its string value at that json path:

```
with tbl as (
  select json '2' j union all
  select json '1' j union all
  select json '"hello"' union all
  select json '"alpha"' union all
  select json '[1,2,3]' union all
  select json '{"x": "zzz"}' union all
  select json '{"x": "abc"}' union all
  select json '{"x": {"z": 2}}'
)
select j, JSON_EXTRACT(j, '$.x') from tbl
order by CASE WHEN JSON_EXTRACT(j, '$.x') IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE TO_JSON_STRING(JSON_EXTRACT(j, '$.x')) END NULLS LAST
```

[image]

Two things here that I'd like to clean up here are:

The `CASE` expression seems wholly unnecessary. I tried using an `IFNULL` function which cleans it up a bit, but even that is rejected because it is not allowed on `JSON`. I have to 'filter out' the `null`s otherwise the `TO_JSON_STRING` will format the SQL null value as the string "null", which I don't want to work, since I'm trying to push `null`s to the end.

What would be a better way to do this query?

---

Note: the following query comes pretty close, but even this takes the (non-string) value of `{"z": 2}` and converts it to `null`, which is a value that I want to sort on as its cast-to-string value.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I follow your explanation correctly, but you can try below.

```sql
with tbl as (
  select json '2' j union all
  select json '1' j union all
  select json '"hello"' union all
  select json '"alpha"' union all
  select json '[1,2,3]' union all
  select json '{"x": "zzz"}' union all
  select json '{"x": "abc"}' union all
  select json '{"x": {"z": 2}}'
)
select j, j.x from tbl
order by NULLIF(FORMAT('%t', j.x), 'NULL') nulls last
```

**Query results**

[image]

- See also  - [How to check if null values present in JSON object column in BigQuery Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74046974/how-to-check-if-null-values-present-in-json-object-column-in-bigquery-table)

Comment: thanks again for this. By the way, how did you get so good at BigQuery? Is this just a case of spending a lot of time with the documentation? Or some other things.

Comment: @David542, thanks for saying that. I don't think I'm such a good at BigQuery like many other experts here on SO.  I've just been using BigQuery heavily at work over serveral years as a data engieer/analyst and also have learned a lot from other experts here on SO for a year.  Especially the efforts to keep up with the BQ documentation and release notes was very helpful to me, I think.